# Can't Create Universal App Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I try to create a new Universal App with C# in VS2013 I get the following errors in sequence:

[image: A problem was encountered created the sub project The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information. 1) No exports were found that match the constraint: ContractName]

[image: The imported project was not found Windows]

[image: The imported project was not found Windows Phone]

I've tried uninstalling any Azure extensions from Visual Studio, but the problem still occurs.  It happens for any app type, not just blanks.

I can see the folder gets created in the Projects folder, but it's completely empty. There are no files what-so-ever created for any of the templates (just a `.sln` file).

Other project types are created fine.

I can't find the VS 2013 installer, so I'm hoping I can fix this without a reinstall or repair install.

Comment: Before we can help, you need to try and repair the installation, all other solutions I have require you at least try that.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll see if I can get someone to download the installer from MSDN for me.